# Python: check same values in the dictionary for two dictionaries with different key

Tags: python, dictionary

There are two dictionaries with different keys name. I want to check if the `'pair'` in `trades_to_make` is  as `instrument` in `open_position`, and `units` in `trades_to_make`and `long.units` or `short.units` in `open_position` are in same direction.

```
if ('pair'.values() in trades_to_make == 'instrument'.values() in open_position) :
    if (('units'.values in trades_to_make and 'long.units' in open_position) >0) or (('units'.values in trades_to_make and 'short.units' in open_position) <0):
          #drop the false element in `trades-to_make`
          keep_dict = {}
          #the drop element in a new dict
          drop_dict = {}
```

The desired output is

```
keep_dict = [{'pair': 'USD_JPY',
      'units': 4655,
      'take_profit': 156.232,
      'stop_loss': 155.428}]
drop_dict = [{'pair': 'USD_SGD',
      'units': -465483,
      'take_profit': 1.26701,
      'stop_loss': 1.27486}]
```

`USD_JPY` has the `units` and `long.units` are both more than 0, so it is in the keep_dict.
`USD_SGD` has the `units` less than 0 and `long.units` more than 0. Since it is not both more than 0 or both less than 0, it is in drop_dict

```
    trades_to_make = [{'pair': 'USD_JPY',
      'units': 4655,
      'take_profit': 156.232,
      'stop_loss': 155.428},
     {'pair': 'USD_SGD',
      'units': -465483,
      'take_profit': 1.26701,
      'stop_loss': 1.27486}]

open_position = [{'instrument': 'USD_JPY',
  'pl': '0.0000',
  'resettablePL': '0.0000',
  'financing': '0.0000',
  'commission': '0.0000',
  'dividendAdjustment': '0.0000',
  'guaranteedExecutionFees': '0.0000',
  'unrealizedPL': '0.0006',
  'marginUsed': '0.0280',
  'long.units': '1',
  'long.averagePrice': '115.515',
  'long.pl': '0.0000',
  'long.resettablePL': '0.0000',
  'long.financing': '0.0000',
  'long.dividendAdjustment': '0.0000',
  'long.guaranteedExecutionFees': '0.0000',
  'long.tradeIDs': ['9585'],
  'long.unrealizedPL': '0.0006',
  'short.units': '0',
  'short.pl': '0.0000',
  'short.resettablePL': '0.0000',
  'short.financing': '0.0000',
  'short.dividendAdjustment': '0.0000',
  'short.guaranteedExecutionFees': '0.0000',
  'short.unrealizedPL': '0.0000',
  'short.averagePrice': nan,
  'short.tradeIDs': nan},
 {'instrument': 'AUD_USD',
  'pl': '-308.6247',
  'resettablePL': '-308.6247',
  'financing': '-132.6313',
  'commission': '0.0000',
  'dividendAdjustment': '0.0000',
  'guaranteedExecutionFees': '0.0000',
  'unrealizedPL': '1222.7585',
  'marginUsed': '8526.2600',
  'long.units': '426313',
  'long.averagePrice': '0.71254',
  'long.pl': '-1800.7434',
  'long.resettablePL': '-1800.7434',
  'long.financing': '-73.8533',
  'long.dividendAdjustment': '0.0000',
  'long.guaranteedExecutionFees': '0.0000',
  'long.tradeIDs': ['12314'],
  'long.unrealizedPL': '1222.7585',
  'short.units': '0',
  'short.pl': '1492.1187',
  'short.resettablePL': '1492.1187',
  'short.financing': '-58.7780',
  'short.dividendAdjustment': '0.0000',
  'short.guaranteedExecutionFees': '0.0000',
  'short.unrealizedPL': '0.0000',
  'short.averagePrice': nan,
  'short.tradeIDs': nan},
 {'instrument': 'USD_SGD',
  'pl': '4111.9010',
  'resettablePL': '4111.9010',
  'financing': '-76.9777',
  'commission': '0.0000',
  'dividendAdjustment': '0.0000',
  'guaranteedExecutionFees': '0.0000',
  'unrealizedPL': '2.1516',
  'marginUsed': '55.9734',
  'long.units': '2000',
  'long.averagePrice': '1.34485',
  'long.pl': '2150.1331',
  'long.resettablePL': '2150.1331',
  'long.financing': '-53.5704',
  'long.dividendAdjustment': '0.0000',
  'long.guaranteedExecutionFees': '0.0000',
  'long.tradeIDs': ['9219', '9229'],
  'long.unrealizedPL': '2.1516',
  'short.units': '0',
  'short.pl': '1961.7679',
  'short.resettablePL': '1961.7679',
  'short.financing': '-23.4073',
  'short.dividendAdjustment': '0.0000',
  'short.guaranteedExecutionFees': '0.0000',
  'short.unrealizedPL': '0.0000',
  'short.averagePrice': nan,
  'short.tradeIDs': nan},
 {'instrument': 'USD_CAD',
  'pl': '-7048.5238',
  'resettablePL': '-7048.5238',
  'financing': '-18.2784',
  'commission': '0.0000',
  'dividendAdjustment': '0.0000',
  'guaranteedExecutionFees': '0.0000',
  'unrealizedPL': '1101.4851',
  'marginUsed': '11931.0968',
  'long.units': '0',
  'long.averagePrice': nan,
  'long.pl': '-3089.4037',
  'long.resettablePL': '-3089.4037',
  'long.financing': '0.0000',
  'long.dividendAdjustment': '0.0000',
  'long.guaranteedExecutionFees': '0.0000',
  'long.tradeIDs': nan,
  'long.unrealizedPL': '0.0000',
  'short.units': '-426313',
  'short.pl': '-3959.1201',
  'short.resettablePL': '-3959.1201',
  'short.financing': '-18.2784',
  'short.dividendAdjustment': '0.0000',
  'short.guaranteedExecutionFees': '0.0000',
  'short.unrealizedPL': '1101.4851',
  'short.averagePrice': '1.27418',
  'short.tradeIDs': ['12318']},
 {'instrument': 'EUR_GBP',
  'pl': '-3066.4302',
  'resettablePL': '-3066.4302',
  'financing': '-302.2728',
  'commission': '0.0000',
  'dividendAdjustment': '0.0000',
  'guaranteedExecutionFees': '0.0000',
  'unrealizedPL': '-137.8529',
  'marginUsed': '13512.9337',
  'long.units': '425564',
  'long.averagePrice': '0.83718',
  'long.pl': '-2519.9944',
  'long.resettablePL': '-2519.9944',
  'long.financing': '-158.5779',
  'long.dividendAdjustment': '0.0000',
  'long.guaranteedExecutionFees': '0.0000',
  'long.tradeIDs': ['12278'],
  'long.unrealizedPL': '-137.8529',
  'short.units': '0',
  'short.pl': '-546.4358',
  'short.resettablePL': '-546.4358',
  'short.financing': '-143.6949',
  'short.dividendAdjustment': '0.0000',
  'short.guaranteedExecutionFees': '0.0000',
  'short.unrealizedPL': '0.0000',
  'short.averagePrice': nan,
  'short.tradeIDs': nan}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, this code should do the trick:

```py
keep_dicts = list()
drop_dicts = list()
for trade in trades_to_make:
    for position in open_position:
        if trade['pair'] == position['instrument']:
            long_unit_float = float(position['long.units'])
            if trade['units'] > 0 and long_unit_float > 0:
                keep_dicts.append(trade)
            elif trade['units'] < 0 and long_unit_float < 0:
                drop_dicts.append(trade)

print(keep_dicts)
print(drop_dicts)
```

Output:

```py
[{'pair': 'USD_JPY', 'units': 4655, 'take_profit': 156.232, 'stop_loss': 155.428}]
[]
```

There is however an inconsistency in the data, if I look at your expected output. The only other entry with `USD_SGD` has a `long.unit` value of `2000` which is greater than `0`. So it should not appear in the `drop_dict` according to your parameters.

But hopefully this code will get you in the right direction.